# Does my motherboard support Intel VT-d?

Tags: motherboard, vt-x

I am trying to enable Intel VT on my machine. My processor is the i7-3610QM and it supports Intel VT-x, but I don't know if my motherboard (Clevo W150ER) supports Intel VT-d.

- How can I find out if the chipsets of my motherboard?
- How do I know if they support Intel VT-d?

Comment: Instead of posting multiple questions I would wait to see if the original question is answered http://superuser.com/questions/592840/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x.

Comment: This is actually something different. Enabling VT-x wont be of any good if my motherboard's chipset doesn't support Intel VT-d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so after many hours of search, I think I know the answer. I will post what I know here in case some one else needs it one day.

How to know if a motherboard supports VT-d? That greatly depends on the chipset it has. In the case for Intel these posts were helpful:

- [Does my product support Intel VT?](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2010/04/02/does-my-product-support-intel-vt)
- [Desktop Boards](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-030922.htm)

I would post more links, but I can only post 2. 
So after hours of searching for the Clevo W150ER motherboard specs, I found that it holds the Intel's Panther Point Model HM76. After searching this model in the previous websites, I realized that it does not support Intel VT-d.